# How to loop through the whole gridview rows including the rows in other pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, gridview, data-paging

I know how to loop through the grid view rows :

---

```
foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows)
{
    //
}
```

---

but what i want to do is looping through the whole gridview including the rows in the other pages if i enable the `paging` .
how to do this ?

Comment: why don't you just loop through your datasource ?

Answer (score 2):

@just_name, you need to remember that any manipulation with server-side objects like GridViewRow is worst way to work with data. If you need any data-driven manipulations - do it in source of data, not with view.

Comment: The problem that i has text boxes as a template fields

Comment: @just_name you can't use binding to bind textbox values to model in source? Can you describe full problem, mb there are better way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cast<T>` or `OfType<T>` to convert to `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>())
{
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>())
{
}
```

In this case it is correct to use both because `Rows` only contains element of `GridViewRow`. But you should not notice the different between two methods:

1. [`Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx): *Casts* the elements to the specified type.
2. [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx): *Filters* the elements based on a specified type.

Comment: hmm,thanks ,but this fixes my problem . If the grid for example has 5 rows and i'm in the last page which has a one row . the loop count is `1` not `5` !!! I wanna to loop through the whole pages not the selected page only .